# Firefox heavy lag when using transform: translateX() in a transition

Tags: css, firefox, transform, translate-animation

What I have is an offcanvas nav that moves the entire page once opened. 
It looks like this:

```
.offcanvas {
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: calc($unit * 8);
    z-index: 3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 420px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: $color-secondary;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transform: translateX(420px);
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

When a button is clicked it gets a class modifier through jquery which moves it inside the window:

```
    &--opened {
        will-change: transform;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

Content is wrapped in main which also gets moved once the nav is opened:

```
.main {
will-change: transform;
transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;

    &__moved {
        will-change: transform;
        transform: translateX(-420px);
    }
}
```

It works just fine in every major browser except Firefox (54.0.1), tested on Windows and OSX. The transition is extremely laggy both when opening and closing the menu. I tried adding *will-change: transform;* but the issue is still there. I've tried using *translate3d* and *left/right*, but those didn't help.

Has anyone experienced these issues and what have you done to solve them?

Thanks!

Comment: I once encountered this problem while animating SVG elements. It worked all good in Chrome but was laggy in Firefox. After some research, I found that Chrome's V8 javascript engine was the reason why there was no lag in Google Chrome. Firefox has a different JS compiler, and it gets laggy for animation having high FPS(frames/second). I lowered the fps and deleted unnecessary animation to solve the problem. Hope this may help.

Comment: @AnkitaChatterjee yes, removing unnecessary animation elements like easing did improve the situation, I also shortened the animation time by .1s and it seems to have helped. However it is still visible, I'll se what I can do about that.

Thank you!